# apk not installing in every phone

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I built my APK from Android Studio and I am testing it on different phones. It installs properly on some phones like Asus Zenfone 2 and Asus Zenfone 3 but it doesn't install on a Samsung Galaxy A5 2016. The error that the phone gives is :

> Package Installation App keeps blocking

This is my manifest if it can help to give some inputs for the actual solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/animaslogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/animaslogo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".splash"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Preghiere"
        android:label="Preghiere" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Canzoni"
        android:label="Canzoni" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Bans"
        android:label="Bans" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Calendario"
        android:label="Calendario" />
    <activity
        android:name=".perRiflettere"
        android:label="Per Riflettere" />
    <activity android:name=".DisplayLiryc" />
    <activity android:name=".DisplayBanVideo" />
    <activity android:name=".Commons" />
    <activity android:name=".Exam" />
    <activity android:name=".rose" />
    <activity android:name=".Just" />
    <activity android:name=".DisplayCommons" />
    <activity android:name=".DisplayJust" />
    <activity android:name=".DisplayMisteri" />
    <activity android:name=".DisplayNews" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".MonthView" />
    <activity android:name=".DisplayEvent" />
    <activity android:name=".DisplayProgramma" />
    <activity android:name=".DisplayVangelo" />
    <activity android:name=".DisplaySanto"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you installing it on these devices or is someone else?  Is it a signed apk downloaded from the play store?  if not, do you have allowed from unknown sources enabled?

Comment: It is exported from Android Studio, i coded it, it is not on google play, I do have unknown sources enabled

Answer (score 0):

Try revoking USB Debugging Authorizations and then re-enabling USB Debugging your device(s).
Also clean and rebuild the project.